# Socket.io HTTP error 400

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

In production we see random error spikes in NewRelic that don't have any stack traces. It simply shows /socket.io and HttpError 400 in the error tab.

Is there a way to get better error reporting for errors like this?
Is this a problem with the nginx proxy we use?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm also having the exact problem

Comment: There was a problem with socket.io being loaded by guests, so the servers were overloaded. I fixed that and we added more resources, the error went away.

Comment: @Eddie How you fixed this problem because we have having same problem